# Can't EXport PPT slide to img file, when Using Qt QAxObject to operate office PowerPoint 2013 by com

Tags: image, pdf, export, powerpoint, office-2013

Using Powerpoint.Application to new QAxObject,
that all fuctions work well when running program with office 2010,
but when i use office 2013 (only install this,not other versions)to run program,
i can open ppt file by "Open(const string&,int,int,int)" method,but "Export(const string&,const string&,Long,Long)" method run error:

QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member Export: Exception thrown by server
            Code       : 16389
            Source     : Microsoft PowerPoint 2013
            Description: Slide.Export : PowerPoint ??? ^0 ??? ^1?
            Help       :
            Connect to the exception(int,QString,QString,QString) signal to catch this

And i try to use "saveas(...)" function to trasfer ppt to pdf,but same result:
QAxBase: Error calling IDispatch member SaveCopyAs: Exception thrown by server
              Code       : 16389
             Source     : Microsoft PowerPoint 2013
              Description: Presentation.SaveCopyAs : PowerPoint ??? ^0 ??? ^1?
             Help       :
             Connect to the exception(int,QString,QString,QString) signal to catch this

office 2013 issue?

Comment: that is a problem about filepath of  windows 10  and windows 7, “/” not equal with "\\" on windows 10,

Comment: finally， i found that the first param of the method "Export(const string&,const string&,Long,Long)" was not correct. exp : ① “C:/test/test/page%d” is not ok.；② “C:\\test\test\page%d” is no ok ； ③ “C:\\test\\test\\page%d” work well –